# Android Studio - Getting Crash for

Tags: android, android-studio, automation

Hi I am trying to run Android Automation Script from Android Studio but its giving one class cast exception as below... Can you please help?

org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.GroovyCastException: Cannot cast object 'org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver@7c8c70d6' with class 'org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver' to class 'io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver'

```
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.DefaultTypeTransformation.continueCastOnSAM(DefaultTypeTransformation.java:392)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.DefaultTypeTransformation.continueCastOnNumber(DefaultTypeTransformation.java:306)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.DefaultTypeTransformation.castToType(DefaultTypeTransformation.java:227)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods.asType(DefaultGroovyMethods.java:12580)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.dgm$48.doMethodInvoke(Unknown Source)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1206)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1015)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.invokePojoMethod(InvokerHelper.java:889)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.invokeMethod(InvokerHelper.java:880)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.invokeMethodN(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:166)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.asType(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:589)
at com.medtronic.neuro.intellis.pageobjects.IntellisApplication.startTestModeApp(IntellisApplication.groovy:152)
at com.medtronic.neuro.intellis.pageobjects.IntellisApplication$startTestModeApp$0.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:49)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:133)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:137)
at com.medtronic.neuro.intellis.pageobjects.IntellisApplication.startCommManagerInTestMode(IntellisApplication.groovy:177)
at com.medtronic.neuro.intellis.at.steps.setup.Setup.configureApplication(Setup.java:152)
at com.medtronic.neuro.intellis.at.steps.setup.Setup.beforeScenario(Setup.java:79)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at cucumber.runtime.Utils$1.call(Utils.java:37)
at cucumber.runtime.Timeout.timeout(Timeout.java:13)
at cucumber.runtime.Utils.invoke(Utils.java:31)
at cucumber.runtime.java.JavaHookDefinition.execute(JavaHookDefinition.java:59)
at cucumber.runtime.Runtime.runHookIfTagsMatch(Runtime.java:222)
at cucumber.runtime.Runtime.runHooks(Runtime.java:210)
at cucumber.runtime.Runtime.runBeforeHooks(Runtime.java:200)
at cucumber.runtime.model.CucumberScenario.run(CucumberScenario.java:44)
at cucumber.runtime.junit.ExecutionUnitRunner.run(ExecutionUnitRunner.java:91)
at cucumber.runtime.junit.FeatureRunner.runChild(FeatureRunner.java:63)
at cucumber.runtime.junit.FeatureRunner.runChild(FeatureRunner.java:18)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
at cucumber.runtime.junit.FeatureRunner.run(FeatureRunner.java:70)
at cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber.runChild(Cucumber.java:93)
at cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber.runChild(Cucumber.java:37)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
at cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber.run(Cucumber.java:98)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:160)
at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:69)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:234)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:74)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)
```

Comment: post the related code and both gradle files

Comment: same code works on Intellij but it doesn't on Android.
I tried dubugging in Intellij, it gives AndroidDriver but on AndroidStudio, it gives HtmlUnitDriver.